# Timeout error when reading octet-stream from azure blob container in Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, memorystream

I have an azure function where I need to fetch an image from an azure blob container and then I send it to an external API. For this I download it to a memorystream and then send it as a stream to the API.

The code I use for this is the following:

```
           var storageConnection = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING");
           var containerName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BlobContainerName");

           var cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnection); 
           var blobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

           var cloudBlobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName); 
           var blockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);

           var memStream = new MemoryStream();
           blockBlob.DownloadToStream(memStream);
```

This works fine with normal images, but somehow doesn't work for items saved as an octet-stream (which occurs when uploading an image via a certain upload page).

Does anyone have any idea why this is and how to fix it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else would have this issue, I fixed it very easily:

instead of

```
var memStream = new MemoryStream();
blockBlob.DownloadToStream(memStream);
```

I used

```
var stream = await blockBlob.OpenReadAsync();
```